# live ip not directing to the react-app index page on lightsail server

Tags: reactjs, amazon-lightsail

I created react-app on amazon light-sail server, and it shows running in the terminal. but when I hit the live IP, it takes me to the by default web page that was there. How to map the live IP with the react-app homepage. Also plz know that it was created in a new folder and then used create-react-app command no previous apps were removed. Its node server where it is installed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved. Actually, the port was not allowed, so once i allowed the port then it started working. Go to Networking and in ipv4 networking add the rule to allow the port.